# (Dis-)Advantage of 2 chainrings / 3 chainrings

Tags: mountain-bike, gears, chainring

I think about buying a new mountainbike when sale is starting.

Now my Problem is that my favorite mountainbike has only 2 chainrings with 36/26 teeth. I am used to ride with 3 chainrings and don't know if it's too hard for me to ride or if it feels like "*some gears are missing*" if there is one chainring less.
I am just a hobby cyclist, I love to do some tours an evening rides, but just for fun.

Maybe someone can explain advantages and disadvantages of 2 vs 3 chainrings.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but I think the typical drivetrain offerings have changed in the four years since the original question was asked. The wider range and greater number of gears available on the cassettes are now being paired with 1 or 2 chainrings on the front. If you are looking at bikes with at least 9 "speeds" in the back (9 cogs on the cassette), a 36/26 front provides all the range most riders will need.

Comment: @Old95rpm thanks! That's an comment I hoped to get here :-)